# When I trying to use *python* command in terminal it writes just 'Python' every time

Tags: python, django

When I trying to use *python* command in terminal it writes just 'Python' every time
example:

```
PS C:\Users\THE WORLD\Desktop\avtobot>python --version
Python
#Or 
PS C:\Users\THE WORLD\Desktop\avtobot>python manage.py makemigrations
Python
:Just like this how can I use this command
```

But it is working when

```
PS C:\Users\THE WORLD\Desktop\avtobot>py --version
Python 3.10.4
But :)
PS C:\Users\THE WORLD\Desktop\avtobot>py manage.py makemigrations
Python
```

and it is writing like this (and i tried to use *python3* too)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with how Python is stored: I always get error about Python not existing when writing python in powershell, but when writing py it immediately creates a python shell.

Comment: According to your given lines you have python 3.10.4 so try python3.